# Solving the heat equation - derivative of an integral

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

I was reading a solution for the heat equation and, at some point, I had to calculate $Q_{x}$, where $$Q(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{4kt}}}e^{-s^2}ds$$
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, perform a simple change of variables in the integral:
$$ u := s\sqrt{4kt}.$$
Next, use the Fundamental theorem of analysis to evaluate the derivative with respect to x.